# How to decode and play back rtp captured packets using Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, rtp, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, decoder

I have captured packets of [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) in Wireshark The captured packets are of .mp3, and now how should I decode these packets, so that I can play them back again in any player?

Is there a way to decode these captured packets, either it be audio or video and make them play again?

Answer (score 1):

There is a functionality provided in Wireshark to capture the RTP streams & then decode them and play it.

You can find it in menu *Telephony* -> *RTP*. And if you are using an old version of Wireshark then it's possible that this functionality is not present.

I have Wireshark version 1.6.8, and it has such a functionality.

Comment: I am streaming a .mp3 song from my pc to other pc and on other pc i open this stream and capture its packets in wireshark, save it as .pcap file and try to play it as you said but no success.